# Android Login not working using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

The android login script is not working, the system is not forwarding the request to server, only output I get is the toast popup indicating network error.
I can't figure out what the problem is, packet capture from the app shows nothing

```
login_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

                    int responseCode;

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                        try {
                            URL url = new URL(Rideshare.SERVER_URL + "/user/login/");
                            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            connection.setDoInput(true);
                            connection.setDoOutput(true);
                            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                            connection.connect();

                            Uri.Builder _data = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("phone", params[0]).appendQueryParameter("password", params[1]);
                            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                            writer.write(_data.build().getEncodedQuery());
                            writer.flush();
                            writer.close();

                            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                            String line;
                            if (responseCode > 199 && responseCode < 300) {
                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    result.append(line);
                                }
                                reader.close();
                                return result.toString();
                            } else {
                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    result.append(line);
                                }
                                reader.close();
                                return result.toString();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

                        if (responseCode == 200) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(s);
                           System.out.print(jsonObj.toString());
                                String results = jsonObj.getString("status");
                                String userId= jsonObj.getString("userId");
                                String displayName= jsonObj.getString("displayName");
                                HashMap<String, String> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                                userInfo.put("USER_ID",userId);
                                userInfo.put("USER_NAME",displayName);
                                userInfo.put("PHONE",userId);
                              Log.d("results", results);
                                if (results.matches("loggedIn"))
                                {
                                    Rideshare.saveUser(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), userInfo);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SOSActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            getActivity().finish();
                                        }
                                    }, 20);

                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }.execute(phoneNumber_EditText.getText().toString(), password_EditText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        register_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        HashMap<String, String> current = Rideshare.getUser(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        if(current != null){
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SOSActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }, 20);
}
```

Comment: Can you write **error message**?

Comment: Did you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in your manifest ?

Comment: @MuhammedGÜNEŞ: It seems the app not connecting with the server, the only error message I get is the Toast message ( which popup when there is some error with login proccess)

Comment: @ZeenaZeek yes, it is there.

Comment: @Eric Liamson, Can you share Error Msg

Comment: on **responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();** line you can get response errror with **InputStream stream = connection.getErrorStream();**